# Как мутить (mute) человека, если он спамит в Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Ищу документацию про мут. Если человек шлет более 3 сообщений за 5 секунд, как сделать проверку таких таймингов сообщений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) решили данную задачу через добавление middleware с [leaky bucket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0).

Готовый для использования код: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/middleware_and_antiflood.py

```py
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.redis import RedisStorage2
from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled

TOKEN = "BOT_TOKEN_HERE"

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = RedisStorage2()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    """Decorator for configuring rate limit and key."""

    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, "throttling_key", key)
        return func

    return decorator


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix="antiflood_"):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: Message, data: dict):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, "throttling_rate_limit", self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(
                handler, "throttling_key", f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}"
            )
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            await self.message_throttled(message, t)
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def message_throttled(self, message: Message, throttled: Throttled):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            key = getattr(
                handler, "throttling_key", f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}"
            )
        else:
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2:
            await message.reply("Too many requests! ")

        await asyncio.sleep(delta)
        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count:
            await message.reply("Unlocked.")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
@rate_limit(5, "start")
async def cmd_test(message: Message):
    await message.reply("Test passed! You can use this command every 5 seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.middleware.setup(ThrottlingMiddleware())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Все что тебе понадобится так это библиотека datetime и telebot.
У меня есть одно решение мы просто будем получать дату отправки сообщений `message.date()` получаем время в unix формате затем его переводим в обыкновенно(человеческое), достаем от туда секунды затем проверяем количество сообщений отправленных в определенный промежуток времени и если за пять секунд у нас более чем три сообщения то мутим его с помощью:`bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date= [сюда время мута])`,
вот как я вижу решение этой задачки.

Comment: чтобы получить секунды в рф времени можно просто написать                                              ```from datetime import datetime
import pytz
seconds = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')).strftime('%S')
print(seconds)```